# how to cross tabulation output as dataset

Tags: r

I used the code below for cross tabulation:

```
data=table(subset(datGSS, select = c("sex", "happy")))
```

In this result format is saved into values format but I would need output saved into dataset format.

Can any one help me in this regard?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [proding a minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610) and edit your post accordingly. I.e., provide input data, the expected output format + what you tried and in what way it failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the result of `table` to `data.frame` (or `as.data.frame`). I guess, `data.frame(data)` should do the job for you but here is an example on a simple data.frame (your example was not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)) :

```
df <- data.frame(col1=factor(letters[1:4]), 
                 col2=factor(LETTERS[1:2]))
> table(df)
col2
col1 A B
a 1 0
b 0 1
c 1 0
d 0 1
```

To convert it to a `data.frame` (the "dataset" class does not exist in R):

```
> as.data.frame(table(df))
  col1 col2 Freq
1    a    A    1
2    b    A    0
3    c    A    1
4    d    A    0
5    a    B    0
6    b    B    1
7    c    B    0
8    d    B    1
```

Is this what you want?

Also, note that RStudio is "just" an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) for R. So that's more an R question than an RStudio one.

Comment: when i exported cross tabulation result into excel observed there is a difference between output result and exported result (transposing result of 2 columns) . So exactly what the output shown is only exported into excel

Comment: so what do you need now?

Comment: what the cross tabulation result is shown as it is format and data is exported into excel

Comment: you want to export the table without the row/column labels into something readable by MS excel?

Comment: As it is output result exported into excel